# What kind of object does [] create in PHP?

Tags: php

I am coming from Python where assigning `[]` to a variable creates a list object.

In PHP, what kind of object is `$data`:

`$data = [];`

Comment: its array......

Answer (score 1):

**Array :**

An array stores multiple values in one single variable.

```
$cars = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"];
```